# Constraints: align in the middle of the top and a button (image) or better solution

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, layout, constraints

This is how my Homescreen of my App looks like:

[iPhone 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6DFy.png)

I want to have a similar layout for iPhone X. But its pretty difficult for me :(

This is how the homescreen looks like on iPhone X with **my** constraints:

[iPhone X (my constraints](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vz9Mi.png)

As you can see, the six buttons are pretty good set, but the heading "AR Note" doesn't fit that nice... My solution would be, that the buttons have on iPhone X a bit more space in between, but then it doesn't fit to iPhone 8, iPhone 8 Plus, iPhone SE...

Or, the simpler (?) version: Put the heading a bit more downwards, like this:

[iPhone X (not working)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/82BbN.png)

Which is not perfect (and doesn't work with my constraint knowledge), but looks better than my actual constraint version...

Maybe someone can help me.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to add view above and below of "AR Note". And set an equal height to them. And also height >= 0. It could help.

Or add "AR Note" to the view container, pin container to the top of superview and bottom to the top of buttons. "AR Note" center vertically.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest trying out `UILayoutGuides` (here's a good article https://useyourloaf.com/blog/goodbye-spacer-views-hello-layout-guides/)

This let's you have equal spacing between the elements that's dynamic per-device.

Alternatively, you could also put the buttons and headings in a UIStackView, then center that StackView in the ViewController.